# date picker option not showing:Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have used a sample coding from this website for displaying the age when we select the date of birth from the calendar which should be shown after clicking the textbox.

```
$('#dob').datepicker

({
    onSelect: function(value, ui) 

{ 
        var today = new Date(), 


            dob = new Date(value), 

            age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970; 

    $('#age').text(age); 


    },

    maxDate: '+0d',  


    yearRange: '1920:2014', 


    changeMonth: true, 


    changeYear: true 


    });
```

Still I could not choose the date from the calendar,should I add any libraries?

Note:I got this code from this website and I dont have an option to comment in that so I posted a new question to get clarified for this doubt.

I have a textbox filed and even if I manually enter the date as DD/MM/YYYY I could not get the age

Comment: You need to add jquery and jquery-UI library to your page. Also make sure you have unique id="dob", it should not be more than one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add jquery and jquery-UI library, and jquery ui css to your page. Also make sure you have unique `id="dob"`, it should not be more than one time.

add library and css by copy paste below links in  tag of your pager, like below :

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
```

You can save local copies of js and css file, just paste google links in your browser and copy - paste the content and save it to respective files.

see this [Datepicker UI example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), click on viewsourcel link at the bottom.

Comment: I have already copy paste these libraries and have created a id for <input id="dob" type="text" / >
<p id="age"></p>
and still I could not get the output or the calendar to select the dates

Comment: can you please share a jsfiddle

Comment: I can see a datepicker on click of input box and can select a date also. but year showing is 1920 and after select it is taking 2014 by default. Also age is coming 0 always.

Comment: Please clear the text box and reselect a different year and again the same year and its working now.Might be some error in the tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PHvYK/455/)  try this, use `onClose` instead of using `onSelect`

Comment: I tried this and does not work and I have also added the libraries and still cannot get the output

Comment: i think you made simple mistake only.check it properly step by step.

Comment: The same coding if we use it in http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/PHvYK/1/ it works and when I do this using Dreamweaver it does not work.